# CSS. Body height equal to document height

Tags: css, height, document, absolute

in situations where the content is small and body height: 100%, the footer is pressed to the bottom of the window, a pop-up absolute very long menu (longer then body height) increases the height of the document, resulting in a lot of free space after the footer. The problem is that the body height is at this point less than the document height.

How, using css, to  force the body height to follow the height of the document.

[Example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swed/ckzwsLcn/)

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}
.ab {
  left: 2em;
  top: 2em;
  right: 10em;
  height: 150vw;
  position: absolute;
  border:1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="ab"></div>
</div>
<style>

</style>
```

upd.
is looking for an css solution.
On JS (jQuery), it can be done some like this:

```
$("body").height($(document).height());
```

Comment: The body IS the document. What element do you want to match body height in you example?

Comment: I apologize for the incorrectness of the notation
I hope a visual picture and example of jQuery will let know you what I want

Comment: Do you want a pure CSS solution? Or is some JavaScript/jQuery allowed?

Comment: see upd - I known js solution, I looking for css..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the `.ab` element having `position: absolute;`. This causes the element to be taken out of the document flow, resulting in the document height not changing.

Change the `.ab` to `position: relative` to fix this, but this might require some other HTML/layout changes.

```js
function addElement() {

  document.getElementById("ab").classList.add("show")
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#ab {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 30px 5vw;
  height: 150vw;
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid yellow;
  display: none;
}

#ab.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div id="ab"></div>
 <button onclick="addElement()">Add tall element</button>
</div>
<style>

</style>
```

Comment: The example is greatly simplified, you will not make the popup menu relative.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the concessions here. Unfortunately the only alternative would involve using JavaScript to to apply a class to the `body` or `main` elements to change their height. As is, with the `.ab` element having `position: absolute;` it won't effect the height of the elements.

Comment: if you want it to affect the height of the other elements then dont use position absolute

Answer (score 0):

you can try this this will increase the height of main div and remove scroll or else u can give overflow-y:scroll

```
    body, html {
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
   .main {
   border: 1px solid red;
   height:100%;
   overflow-y:scroll;
   position:relative;
}
.ab {
  left: 2em;
  top: 2em;
  right: 10em;
  height: 150vw;
  position: absolute;
  border:1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="ab"></div>
</div>
<style>

</style>
```

Comment: it seems that you need .. I will check in my project on a dynamically pop-up menu. It work on https://jsfiddle.net/swed/ckzwsLcn/9/

Comment: oh no.. mistake it hidden !

Comment: yeah sure ...by the way what do you mean by "it seems that you need.."

Comment: I hurried to the answer without seeing that part of the "pop-up menu" is hidden in the example

Comment: you can check for overflow-y:scroll

Comment: Yeah. I Try some variants :) https://jsfiddle.net/swed/ckzwsLcn/10/ overflow-y:auto is interesting,but it hase scrolling :(

Comment: Please, correct you answer - set scroll or auto. is the most suitable yet